# How to restrict 360 degree viewer to stop on 180 degree view - so the back would be hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, 360-degrees

I used jQuery plugin for creating draggable 360-degree viewer: 
http://nick-jonas.github.io/threesixtyjs/.

The Object for the viewer is an Exhibition stand and I want to restrict the view to 180 degrees because there's no back view of the object available. By restricting the view I mean stopping the 'rotation' of an object once it reaches one of the side views. With the existing code, because of the lack of the back view, when dragging, the view jumps from one side view to the opposite when rotating.

Is it possible to make some changes to the existing Javascript code to achieve this result?

The HTML/CSS/JS are as follows:

```js
/*!
 * ThreeSixty: A jQuery plugin for generating a draggable 360 preview from an image sequence.
 * Version: 0.1.2
 * Original author: @nick-jonas
 * Website: http://www.nickjonas.nyc
 * Licensed under the Apache License Version 2.0
 */

;(function ( $, _window, document ) {


var scope,
    pluginName = 'threeSixty',
    defaults = {
        dragDirection: 'horizontal',
        useKeys: false,
        draggable: true
    },
    dragDirections = ['horizontal', 'vertical'],
    options = {},
    $el = {},
    data = [],
    total = 0,
    loaded = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param {jQuery Object} element       main jQuery object
     * @param {Object} customOptions        options to override defaults
     */
    function ThreeSixty( element, customOptions ) {
        scope = this;
        this.element = element;
        options = options = $.extend( {}, defaults, customOptions) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        // make sure string input for drag direction is valid
        if($.inArray(options.dragDirection, dragDirections) < 0){
            options.dragDirection = defaults.dragDirection;
        }

        this.init();
    }

    // PUBLIC API -----------------------------------------------------

    $.fn.destroy = ThreeSixty.prototype.destroy = function(){
        if(options.useKeys === true) $(document).unbind('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
        $(this).removeData();
        $el.html('');
    };

    $.fn.nextFrame = ThreeSixty.prototype.nextFrame = function(){
        $(this).each(function(i){
            var $this = $(this),
                val = $this.data('lastVal') || 0,
                thisTotal = $this.data('count');

            val = val + 1;

            $this.data('lastVal', val);

            if(val >= thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
            else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
            if(val > 0) val = thisTotal - val;

            val = Math.abs(val);

            $this.find('.threesixty-frame').css({display: 'none'});
            $this.find('.threesixty-frame:eq(' + val + ')').css({display: 'block'});
        });
    };

    $.fn.prevFrame = ThreeSixty.prototype.prevFrame = function(){
        $(this).each(function(i){
            var $this = $(this),
                val = $this.data('lastVal') || 0,
                thisTotal = $this.data('count');

            val = val - 1;

            $this.data('lastVal', val);

            if(val >= thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
            else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
            if(val > 0) val = thisTotal - val;

            val = Math.abs(val);

            $this.find('.threesixty-frame').css({display: 'none'});
            $this.find('.threesixty-frame:eq(' + val + ')').css({display: 'block'});
        });
    };



    // PRIVATE METHODS -------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Initializiation, called once from constructor
     * @return null
     */
    ThreeSixty.prototype.init = function () {
        var $this = $(this.element);

        // setup main container
        $el = $this;

        // store data attributes for each 360
        $this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                link = $this.data('link'),
                count = $this.data('count');
            data.push({'link': link, 'count': count, 'loaded': 0, '$el': $this});
            total += count;
        });

        _disableTextSelectAndDragIE8();

        this.initLoad();
    };

    /**
     * Start loading all images
     * @return null
     */
    ThreeSixty.prototype.initLoad = function() {
        var i = 0, len = data.length, url, j;
        $el.addClass('preloading');
        for(i; i < len; i++){
            j = 0;
            for(j; j < data[i].count; j++){
                url = data[i].link.replace('{index}', j);
                $('<img/>').data('index', i).attr('src', url).load(this.onLoadComplete);
            }
        }
    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onLoadComplete = function(e) {
        var index = $(e.currentTarget).data('index'),
            thisObj = data[index];
        thisObj.loaded++;
        if(thisObj.loaded === thisObj.count){
            scope.onLoadAllComplete(index);
        }
    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onLoadAllComplete = function(objIndex) {
        var $this = data[objIndex].$el,
            html = '',
            l = data[objIndex].count,
            linkTemplate = data[objIndex].link,
            i = 0;

        // remove preloader
        $this.html('');
        $this.removeClass('preloading');

        // add 360 images
        for(i; i < l; i++){
            var display = (i === 0) ? 'block' : 'none';
            html += '<img class="threesixty-frame" style="display:' + display + ';" data-index="' + i + '" src="' + linkTemplate.replace('{index}', i) + '"/>';
        }
        $this.html(html);

        this.attachHandlers(objIndex);
    };

    var startY = 0,
        thisTotal = 0,
        $downElem = null,
        lastY = 0,
        lastX = 0,
        lastVal = 0,
        isMouseDown = false;
    ThreeSixty.prototype.attachHandlers = function(objIndex) {
        var that = this;
        var $this = data[objIndex].$el;

        // add draggable events
        if(options.draggable){
            // if touch events supported, use
            if(typeof document.ontouchstart !== 'undefined' &&
                typeof document.ontouchmove !== 'undefined' &&
                typeof document.ontouchend !== 'undefined' &&
                typeof document.ontouchcancel !== 'undefined'){
                var elem = $this.get()[0];
                elem.addEventListener('touchstart', that.onTouchStart);
                elem.addEventListener('touchmove', that.onTouchMove);
                elem.addEventListener('touchend', that.onTouchEnd);
                elem.addEventListener('touchcancel', that.onTouchEnd);
            }
        }

        // mouse down
        $this.mousedown(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            thisTotal = $(this).data('count');
            $downElem = $(this);
            startY = e.screenY;
            lastVal = $downElem.data('lastVal') || 0;
            lastX = $downElem.data('lastX') || 0;
            lastY = $downElem.data('lastY') || 0;
            isMouseDown = true;
            $downElem.trigger('down');
        });

        // arrow keys
        if(options.useKeys === true){
            $(document).bind('keydown', that.onKeyDown);
        }

        // mouse up
        $(document, 'html', 'body').mouseup(that.onMouseUp);
        $(document).blur(that.onMouseUp);
        $('body').mousemove(function(e){
            that.onMove(e.screenX, e.screenY);
        });
    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onTouchStart = function(e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        e.preventDefault();
        $downElem = $(e.target).parent();
        thisTotal = $downElem.data('count');
        startX = touch.pageX;
        startY = touch.pageY;
        lastVal = $downElem.data('lastVal') || 0;
        lastX = $downElem.data('lastX') || 0;
        lastY = $downElem.data('lastY') || 0;
        isMouseDown = true;
        $downElem.trigger('down');
    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onTouchMove = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        scope.onMove(touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onTouchEnd = function(e) {

    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onMove = function(screenX, screenY){
        if(isMouseDown){
            var x = screenX,
                y = screenY,
                val = 0;

            $downElem.trigger('move');

            if(options.dragDirection === 'vertical'){
                if(y > lastY){
                    val = lastVal + 1;
                }else{
                    val = lastVal - 1;
                }
            }else{
                if(x > lastX){
                    val = lastVal + 1;
                }else if(x === lastX){
                    return;
                }else{
                    val = lastVal - 1;
                }
            }

            lastVal = val;
            lastY = y;
            lastX = x;

            $downElem.data('lastY', lastY);
            $downElem.data('lastX', lastX);
            $downElem.data('lastVal', lastVal);

            if(val >= thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
            else if(val <= -thisTotal) val = val % (thisTotal - 1);
            if(val > 0) val = thisTotal - val;

            val = Math.abs(val);

            $downElem.find('.threesixty-frame').css({display: 'none'});
            $downElem.find('.threesixty-frame:eq(' + val + ')').css({display: 'block'});
        }
    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onKeyDown = function(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37: // left
                $el.prevFrame();
                break;
            case 39: // right
                $el.nextFrame();
                break;
        }
    };

    ThreeSixty.prototype.onMouseUp = function(e) {
        isMouseDown = false;
        $downElem.trigger('up');
    };

    /**
     * Disables text selection and dragging on IE8 and below.
     */
    var _disableTextSelectAndDragIE8 = function() {
      // Disable text selection.
      document.body.onselectstart = function() {
          return false;
      };

      // Disable dragging.
      document.body.ondragstart = function() {
          return false;
      };
    };


    /**
     * A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
        preventing against multiple instantiations
     * @param  {Object} options
     * @return {jQuery Object}
     */
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new ThreeSixty( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@-webkit-keyframes ui-spinner-rotate-right {
  /* line 58, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 59, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 60, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 61, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  /* line 62, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ui-spinner-rotate-left {
  /* line 66, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 67, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 68, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 69, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 70, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes ui-spinner-rotate-right {
  /* line 74, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 75, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  25% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 76, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 77, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  75% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  /* line 78, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes ui-spinner-rotate-left {
  /* line 82, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 83, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  25% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 84, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 85, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  75% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 86, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ui-spinner-rotate-right {
  /* line 90, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 91, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 92, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 93, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  /* line 94, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes ui-spinner-rotate-left {
  /* line 98, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 99, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  25% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  /* line 100, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 101, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  75% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  /* line 102, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

/* line 110, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
/* line 114, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner .side {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
/* line 120, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner .side .fill {
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
/* line 130, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner .side-left {
  left: 0;
}
/* line 133, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner .side-left .fill {
  left: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-left;
  -moz-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-left;
  -ms-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-left;
  -o-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-left;
  animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
/* line 142, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner .side-right {
  left: 50%;
}
/* line 145, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner .side-right .fill {
  left: -100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-right;
  -moz-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-right;
  -ms-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-right;
  -o-animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-right;
  animation-name: ui-spinner-rotate-right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

/* line 1, ../../scss/_ui.scss */
.ui {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
/* line 6, ../../scss/_ui.scss */
.ui .next {
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 17px;
}
/* line 14, ../../scss/_ui.scss */
.ui .prev {
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 17px;
}

/* line 26, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  background: #dddddd;
}
/* line 31, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner .side .fill {
  background: #3c76ca;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
  -o-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* line 39, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
.ui-spinner:after {
  content: "";
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  display: block;
}

/* line 11, ../../scss/main.scss */
body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: roc-grotesk, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* line 39, ../../scss/main.scss */
body .threesixty-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/* line 43, ../../scss/main.scss */
body .threesixty-wrapper .threesixty {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  
}
/* line 26, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
body .threesixty-wrapper .threesixty .ui-spinner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #c2fccc;
}
/* line 31, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
body .threesixty-wrapper .threesixty .ui-spinner .side .fill {
  background: #55fc5a;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
  -o-animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* line 39, ../../scss/_ui-spinner.scss */
body .threesixty-wrapper .threesixty .ui-spinner:after {
  content: "";
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: block;
}
/* line 49, ../../scss/main.scss */
body .threesixty-wrapper .threesixty .ui-spinner {
  margin: 270px auto;
}
/* line 54, ../../scss/main.scss */
body .threesixty-wrapper .label {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.threesixty img {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ThreeSixty</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/spl8uhp.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="threesixty-wrapper">

            <div class="threesixty" data-link="https://ergoncreative-my.sharepoint.com/personal/anna_ergoncreative_com/Documents/src/Finnplay{index}.png" data-count="19">
                <!-- put your preloader here -->
                <div class="ui-spinner">
                    <span class="side side-left">
                        <span class="fill"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="side side-right">
                        <span class="fill"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- end preloader -->
            </div>

            <div class="ui">
                <div class="next">next frame</div>
                <div class="prev">previous frame</div>
            </div>

            <img src="assets/img/label.png" alt="" class="label"/>

        </div>

        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var $threeSixty = $('.threesixty');

                $threeSixty.threeSixty({
                    dragDirection: 'horizontal',
                    useKeys: true,
                    draggable: true
                });

                $('.next').click(function(){
                    $threeSixty.nextFrame();
                });

                $('.prev').click(function(){
                    $threeSixty.prevFrame();
                });

                $threeSixty.on('down', function(){
                    $('.ui, h1, h2, .label, .examples').stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300);
                });

                $threeSixty.on('up', function(){
                    $('.ui, h1, h2, .label, .examples').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 500);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That site didn't work for me as https, but the http version works: http://nick-jonas.github.io/threesixtyjs/  Looking at the docs at https://github.com/nick-jonas/threesixtyjs, it seems you can set `draggable` to `false`, and then use the events and `prevFrame` and `nextFrame` to manually control it.  Simply keep track of the amount of rotation and don't advance the frame if it's at a limit.

Comment: @user2740650 thanks, but I want to keep the ability to rotate the object by dragging it. I'm able to stop the functions prevFrame & nextFrame when it reaches either side edges, but cannot understand how to stop it when dragging.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the events section, it shows an example of listening to down, move and up.  So you could manually call `prevFrame` and `nextFrame` as the mouse moves (it would still appear to be draggable -- it's just that you're taking over control of draggging).